# Real matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

A is real matrix from order nXn.
We know that A gives : $<Av,v>=0$ for v vector in $R^n$.

So what must exist?

1. Every eigenvalue of A is real.
2. A is not Invertible
3. A is Hermitian
4. A is not Hermitian
5. all answers are incorrect

I think 2 is the right answer ( can be more than 1 answer that are true) but im not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a counter-example to 1 and 3. The zero matrix is a counter example to 4.

Comment: This is also a counter-example to 2. So 5 is the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, the identity matrix is a counter example to 4.

Comment: No, the identity matrix does not fulfill the condition $<Av,v>=0$ for all $v$.